# Can python do string operations without copying the string memory

Tags: python

I am writing a program to help me parse a **VERY** long log. We are talking 100s of thousands of lines. The goal of course is to get summary data quickly which means being conscientious of memory concerns.

The log contains multiple parts/steps within it. Now the log is read into a string and I go through and make a list of the start and end indexes of the tests.

My goal is to quickly figure out the following

- How many lines are in the file
- Whether it contains the string "Assert.java"
- Whether it contains the string "[SEVERE ]"

I am currently doing it like this

```
    numLines = logFileString[rec["startMarker"]:rec["endMarker"]].count("\n")
    foundAssert = "Assert.java" in logFileString[rec["startMarker"]:rec["endMarker"]]
    foundFailure = "[SEVERE ]" in logFileString[rec["startMarker"]:rec["endMarker"]]
```

My thought process being if I put `logFileString[rec["startMarker"]:rec["endMarker"]]` into a variable for re-use it would for sure force Python to copy that slice of the string (which could be thousands of lines) into a variable. Perhaps not doing so means python can optimize by just streaming through the file or something.

I dont want to make the code much more complex but I also want to reduce the latency this code takes to run. I know I could measure the timing to determine what is faster but I want to learn more about how **python3** handles string data during these operations and I dont know where to begin.

My question is essentially: Is what I am doing now forcing python to copy that large portion of the string? Is there a more efficient way I could be getting these three metrics?

I have no idea what optimizations Python might employ here.

Comment: String slices **always produce new strings**. Assigning to a variable *is always irrelevant* to this fact (and really, for anything else in CPython). You *can* work with a `memoryview` where slices do not create copies (they create other views).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so saving it to one variable THEN doing these operations on the variable would cause the least amount of copies?

Comment: Well, yes, if you are going to take the slice multiple times Python will do exactly what you say, create and *return a new string* based on your slicing parameters. If you don't want to needlessly keep doing that, then saving a reference to the already sliced string would prevent it from happening again and again needlessly.

Comment: "String slices always produce new lists" typo - new strings, not new lists.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes, thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to check out the [`str.find` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and the `start` and `end` parameters for `find` and `count`.

Comment: Although really, the biggest time and space savings might come from just not reading this whole log file into memory.

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization. Even several 100 thousand lines is a) read in a fraction of a second and 2) sounds like a task you do in a line oriented fashion.

Comment: I just happen to have a 250k line log file here. `wc -l` counts those lines in `0.008 secs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my comments.

I first would get a program running, THEN worry about speed and efficiency.

Python will read millions of lines per second from a text file; your file read speed should not be an issue. Tapes, mercifully, have been retired!

You also are describing a process that is line oriented. ie, You do not need to read the entire file into memory.

If this is so, try something along these lines:

```
found=[]

with open(ur_file) as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if any(test in line for test in ("Assert.java", "[SEVERE ]")):
            found.append((i, line.rstrip())) 

print(f'Total Lines: {i:,}')
print('lines with tests found: {}'.format('\n'.join(map(str, found))))
```

(Not tested...)